# how to extract exactly those element from a column which is given in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

In the given data below  q is a list with some data and i want that if same data is present in z then only the element will appear

```
 q=["q","e","z"]


 data frame
    0
   "q"
   "w"
   "e"
   "t"
   "e"
   "g"
   "t"
   "j"
   "k"
   "u"
   "z"
```

desired result is

```
 z="q"
   "e"
   "e"
   "z"
```

Comment: Various way to do it. Check `in`, `all` for increasing efficiency when `q` is large make it into `set`

Comment: What is `z`? A list? A string?

Comment: @timgeb no z is not a list its a column of a data set

Comment: Then please post it as such, with the exact output you require.

Comment: @varshashubham Are you working with pandas?

Comment: @Ch3steR yes i am working with pandas

Comment: Googling "python find elements in a list which exist in another list" does not show any relevant info?

Comment: @varshashubham Take a look at `pd.Series.str.contains` that would solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still applicable if the data in 'z' is from a column of data, i.e. pandas or a list...the provided answer would need very light modification

```
q
Out[11]: ['q', 'e', 'z']

z
Out[12]: ['q', 'w', 'e', 't', 'e', 'g', 't', 'j', 'k', 'u', 'z']

a = [ q_elm for q_elm in q for z_elm in z if q_elm==z_elm ]

a
Out[14]: ['q', 'e', 'e', 'z']

import pandas as pd

z = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'someFancyKey':z})

z
Out[17]: 
    0
0   q
1   w
2   e
3   t
4   e
5   g
6   t
7   j
8   k
9   u
10  z

a = [ q_elm for q_elm in q for z_elm in z['someFancyKey'] if q_elm==z_elm ]

a
Out[19]: ['q', 'e', 'e', 'z']
```

Comment: For vectorized solution `s[s.str.contains('|'.join(['q','e','z']))]` where `s` is your column.